# Ajax post doesn't work with html in parameters in combination with .net 4 framework

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, .net-4.0

After upgrading our project to the .net 4.0 framework (from 3.5), we facing some problems with ajax calls with html in the parameters. As soon as the user enters some html in a text area the ajax call isn't executed anymore. If the user enters plain text only, there is no problem.

```
   <script language="javascript">
/* Doesn't work */
var html = "<p>test</p>";
var body = "default.aspx?html=" + urlEncode(html);
var des = new AJAXInteraction(url, handleResponse, 'saveloader');
des.doPost(body);

/* Work */
var html = "test";
var body = "default.aspx?html=" + urlEncode(html);
var des = new AJAXInteraction(url, handleResponse, 'saveloader');
des.doPost(body);
</script>
```

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here: http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2010/06/validaterequestfalse-not-working-in-net.html.
In ASP.NET 4, by default, request validation is enabled for all requests and the validateRequest setting per page is ignored.

To revert to the behavior of the ASP.NET 2.0 request validation feature, add the following setting in the Web.config file:

```
<system.web>
 <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably setting `validateRequest` in your page directive to false, will solve your problem. Do this in the Page you're posting to:

```
<%@ Page validateRequest="false" %>
```

ASP.NET by default checks requests for potentially dangerous inputs like HTML code and blocks such requests. Keep in mind that you have to sanitize the input yourself when disabling request validation!

You can read more about it here: http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/request-validation

Comment: validateRequest was already false,
so this is not the solution unfortunately

Comment: Yeah, did not notice your first sentence... :-) But fortunately you found the answer yourself